# opencv/cv2/opencv-python name mismatch, how to convince pip to not look for package already installed through conda?

Tags: python, opencv, pip, anaconda

The python opencv bindings are included with the package called [`opencv`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) on conda-forge or as [`opencv-python`](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) on pypi.  Installing `opencv` on conda-forge makes available the `cv2` module.  Yet after installing this through conda and `pip install`ing a package depending on opencv, `pip install` does not find the existing package.  Depending on what the package is called in `setup.py`, it either searches for the package and fails to find it, or finds it and installs it alongside the conda version.

```
$ conda list | grep opencv
opencv                    4.1.0            py37h5517eff_4    conda-forge
```

If the name in `setup.py` is `opencv`, it will search (even though there already is an `opencv`) but not find:

```
$ pip install .
Processing /home/gholl/checkouts/fogpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.2 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=1.4.2 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (3.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyorbital>=1.5.0 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: trollimage>=1.8.0 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (1.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: satpy>=0.15 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (0.15.1+38.gc7161c08)
Requirement already satisfied: pyresample>=1.11 in /media/nas/x21324/miniconda3/envs/py37d/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (1.11.2)
Collecting opencv>=4.1 (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv>=4.1 (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv>=4.1 (from fogpy==1.1.3+dev92.gb109242.temp)
```

If the name in `setup.py` is `opencv-python`, it will install a second `opencv` alongside the first, and importing the `cv2` module will result in an undefined symbol error.

How can I convince pip to recognise condas installation of opencv?

Comment: In general, using multiple package managers in the same environment is a bad idea, and yours is a good example why. Why do you need to use pip for? Doesn't your package have a conda equivalent? Maybe you could add it. Or you can uninstall the opencv installed with conda and install it with pip.

Comment: @Paul92 I use pip because I'm installing it directly from a github branch, it is not released.